# using jquery each method and get data from table MVC Model

Tags: c#, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I have table about product and price and i'm getting  data using MVC Model and now i'm trying use those datas on my graphics charts but i cannot get  data from my table.How can i get ?

this is table's HTML codes

```
   <tbody id="table2">


        @foreach(var oge in Model)
        {
            <tr onclick="method(this)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">
                <td id="product_name">@Html.Raw(oge.product_name)</td>
                <td id="product_price">@Html.Raw(oge.product_price)</td>              
            </tr>
        }

    </tbody>
```

and this is jquery code using each method,notes :  only using this table,there is no other  element on page.

```
 $("#button").click(function() {          
        $("td").each(function (index,value) {
            alert(index + ": " + value);
        }
        );
    });
```

after execution codes result is;
0:htmlCell...
1:htmlcell...
.
.
.

Comment: Chance `+ value` to `+ $(this).text()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's all works,thank you!

Comment: When you do this `$('td')` jquery will select all `td` elements and when you loop through it using `each`, you will get each `td` element in `value` and when you do `alert` it will just call `value.toString()` and thus produce `htmlCell`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use value, access the content using value.innerText but I agree with the comment above suggesting to use $(this).text()

```
   $("#table2 td").each(function (index,value) {
        console.log(index + ": " + value.innerText);
        console.log(index + ": " + $(this).text());
    });
```